# Is this a non-inductive ceramic resistor?

Tags: resistors, inductance

I found some resistors in my stash which are similar to those ceramic resistors advertised as non-inductive resistor on the internet:

[image]

- Is this a non-inductive ceramic resistor?
- How do I determine the inductance of this resistor or roughly guesstimate?
- What does the bottom right marking means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a non-inductive ceramic resistor?

Looks like it

> How do I determine the inductance of this resistor or roughly
> guesstimate?

Run a square wave through it and look at the rise times, or do a frequency sweep and characterize the roll off with a known amplitude. Smart tweezers might also work. Or try this: https://www.circuitsgallery.com/measuring-inductance-with-oscilloscope/

Basically you have a series RL circuit and you know the resistance (20mΩ) You need to find L.

> What does the bottom right marking means?

Probably company or product logo